# Angular html5Mode not working with ui-router and Gulp

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, gulp, html5-history

A sample of my code for handling routes:

```
app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider', 
  function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {

  $stateProvider
    .state( ... )
    .state( ... )
    .state( ... )

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

  $locationProvider
    .html5Mode(true)
    .hashPrefix('!');
}]);
```

I am able to verify that $locationProvider is working insofar as commenting out .hashPrefix('!') succeeds in removing the bang from the URL, but no matter what I do, nothing seems to actually enable html5Mode; the hash always remains.

I used the Yeoman gulp-angular generator (rather, generator-gulp-angular, https://github.com/Swiip/generator-gulp-angular) and have tried changing up the settings for how my server works, but nothing I've tried there has worked yet.

Comment: Have you tried placing `<base href="/">` at the top of your `<head>` tag?

Comment: which browser are you using to test your urls? and which server are you using, and what do your server routes look like? We need a bit more information to really know what's going on here.

Comment: I have set the base tag but it's not `<base href="/">`; instead it's `<base href="/content/html/">` since we're using our index folder not as the root of our site but to display an index or site map of all the discrete pages / states on the site. I've been using the latest release of Chrome on OSX so I wouldn't expect any issue re: the html5 History API not being available.